# Can I use the login and register process(in Developer Account) with visualforce pages for further bookings by a customer?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforce1-app

Can I use the login and register process(in Developer Account) with visualforce pages for online bookings by a customer?

I have the requirement for online booking by the customer. I want the link on Visualforce Page of Login and register that will only allow the customer to make the final online booking and payment after successful login. Successful registration will generate the customer account and through that (Visualforce Page) the customer can book online. The booking transaction should be stored in the object only after payment confirmation. Can I do payment procedure by customer with Visualforce Page?

Comment: This question is really unclear. I think it requires a bit more explanation than you've given us to go on.

Comment: Edited Post...please review it.

Comment: That's good extra information, so I've re-opened for more input from people, but it's still a little confusing. It sounds like maybe you want to be using customer communities?

Comment: @LaceySnr can i do without using communities or only by using visualforce pages,classes and objects?

Comment: Anybody knows please answer!!!!